# Lie rings: reference request

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, ring-theory, lie-algebras, noncommutative-algebra

Dear friends: I am looking for a modern reference for Lie rings (In particular, I would like to have nice references for the structure of Lie ideals), let it be lecture notes or a book, in the sense that Herstein's "Topics in Ring Theory" is now a bit old, and I want a substitute for this one. If it is possible, I would like it to include most of the classical theorems.

Much thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several books available, but mostly within a certain context. For Lie rings in characteristic $p$ there is a strong relationship to $p$-groups. Here are several books on group theory which deal with Lie rings, e.g., the book of E. L. Khukhro,
[Nilpotent groups and their automorphisms](http://books.google.at/books/about/Nilpotent_Groups_and_Their_Automorphisms.html?id=8ZfjFQvX6n0C&redir_esc=y). Chapter $3$ is on associated Lie rings. 
Lie rings over characteristic zero are often included in books on Lie algebras. A list of references, also for Lie rings, is given [here](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Lie_algebra). In particular, N. Jacobson has written several books dealing with Lie rings, e.g. "Structure of Rings", "Lie algebras", etc.